# iPhone 6s / RoboVM (?) GLTexImage2D rendering issue

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, robovm

we finally released our indie game on the App Store just to find that we have major rendering issues with iPhone 6s.

The game is developed using LibGDX and RoboVM (v.1.12)

We are using the iOS native graphics libraries to render unicode text to a texture to pass it to LibGDX to display as an image. 
To do so we first create the string we want to print and then call its draw() method:

```
    final String tmp = text.substring(0, text.length() >= MAX_NAME_LEN ? MAX_NAME_LEN : text.length());

    final NSMutableString string = new NSMutableString(tmp.length());
    //Allocate space for the bitmap to draw on
    int w = (int) width;
    int h = (int) height;
    final int bufferLen = w * h;
    final CGBitmapContext context = new CGBitmapContext(
        w, h, 8, 0, CGColorSpace.deviceRGB(), CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast
    );

    final CGColor bgColor = UIColor.clear().getCGColor();

    final CGRect rect = new CGRect(0, 0, width, height);

    string.setString(tmp);

    final UIColor textColor = new UIColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a);
    final UIFont font = UIFont.getBoldSystemFont(size);

    final NSString tester = new NSString("a");
    final CGSize textSize = tester.getSize(font);
    int strLen = string.toString().length();

    /**
     * Computes the optimal length of the string and removes characters beyound the
     * screen bounduaries.
     * If the string has been reduced, appends an ellipsis at the end
     */
    final NSRange range = new NSRange();
    boolean removed = false;
    while (strLen > 0 && textSize.getWidth() * strLen > width - textSize.getWidth() * 2) {
        range.setLocation(strLen - 1);
        range.setLength(1);
        string.deleteCharacters(range);

        strLen = string.toString().length();
        removed = true;
    }
    //append ellipsis at the end if we removed a char
    if (removed) {
        string.append("\u2026");
    }

    context.setFillColor(bgColor);
    context.fillRect(rect);
    //set up drawing attributes
    final NSAttributedStringAttributes attributes = new NSAttributedStringAttributes();
    attributes.set(NSAttributedStringAttribute.Font, font);
    attributes.set(NSAttributedStringAttribute.ForegroundColor, textColor);
    final NSMutableParagraphStyle paragraphStyle = new NSMutableParagraphStyle();
    paragraphStyle.setParagraphStyle(NSParagraphStyle.getDefaultParagraphStyle());
    paragraphStyle.setLineBreakMode(NSLineBreakMode.TruncatingTail);
    attributes.set(NSAttributedStringAttribute.ParagraphStyle, paragraphStyle);

    final NSAttributedString finalStr = new NSAttributedString(string.toString(), attributes);

    UIGraphics.pushContext(context);
    context.setTextMatrix(CGAffineTransform.Identity());
    context.translateCTM(0f, h);
    context.scaleCTM(1, -1);
    finalStr.draw(new CGPoint(rect.getX(), (rect.getY() + textSize.getHeight()) / 2));
    UIGraphics.popContext();


    return new BufferTextureData((int)context.getWidth(), (int)context.getHeight(), 0, GL20.GL_RGBA, GL20.GL_RGBA, GL20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, context.getData().asIntBuffer(bufferLen));
```

TextureBufferData then binds the Buffer to a texture in the following way:

```
private Buffer data;

public BufferTextureData(int width, int height, int mipMapLevel, int internalFormat, int format, int type, Buffer data) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.mipLevel = mipMapLevel;
    this.internalFormat = internalFormat;
    this.format = format;
    this.type = type;
    this.data = data;
}

[...]

@Override
public void consumeCustomData(final int target) {
    Gdx.app.debug("BufferTextureData", "consuming data for target: " + target);
    Gdx.gl20.glTexImage2D(target, mipLevel, internalFormat, width, height, 0, format, type, data);
    data = null;
}
```

We tested this code without any issues on those devices:
- iPhone 6
- iPad Air 2
- iPhone 5s
And also on the iPhone 6s simulator.

**The problem is that on a iPhone 6s actual device we get this:**

[image]

As you can see, the text is completely distorted. It seems that the buffer holding the drawing data gets written during the drawcall but we made sure to call that method on the drawing thread to avoid GL context switches.

We really have no clue where to look for.
The fact that the code seamlessly works on the iPhone6s Simulator (x64 CPU) and all the other devices makes me think that the issue is either hardware dependent or caused by the way RoboVM handles memory, but it's just a guess.

*Does anyone has experienced the same issue or have an idea about what could cause this behaviour?*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @datenwolf for pointing us to a good direction.

The problem was somehow due to this "known bug" of the iphone 6s:

http://ios9news.net/fix-ios-9-apps-zoomed-in-on-iphone-6s/

that is, given the same resolution and ppi of the iphone 6, the 6s thinks that he is a bit wider.
Thus our game units that were made as such to be POT multiples were of odd length in 6s devices (for example a width of 480px on an iphone 6 was 561px on an iphone 6s).

When we created a graphics context with `CGContextCreate` we didn't specified how many bytes per row to consider and we let the device to decide for us. It turned out that the OS was adding padding to each row, messing up all the stride and alignments.

The fix was to change:

```
final CGBitmapContext context = new CGBitmapContext(
        w, h, 8, 0, CGColorSpace.deviceRGB(), CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast
    );
```

to:

```
final CGBitmapContext context = new CGBitmapContext(
        w, h, 8, 4 * w, CGColorSpace.deviceRGB(), CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alignment and/or row stride issue. I suggest you read the manual on glPixelStore and its GL_UNPACK_… parameters. You have to set the pixel store parameters to match your image data before loading it with glTexImage